# How can I automatically create a <tr> tag in a table after every third <td> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table that looks like that

[image]

Let's say for whatever reason I'm not able to place new `<tr>` tags between my  `<td>` tags. Is there a way I can achieve that the output of my table in the browser looks like this by styling my table tag with CSS?

[image]

So in my case I need an automatically generated `<tr>` tag after every third `<td>` tag.

Solutions with JS are also welcome

Comment: Show first what you tried

Comment: You can change the DOM of an element with JS, not with CSS. What did you try to achieve your desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you are expecting, but I think this is what you need to generate dynamic rows and col inside the table

```
function generate_table() {
   var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
   var tbl = document.createElement("table");
   var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

    // creating all cells
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       // creates a table row
       var row = document.createElement("tr");

       for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        // Create a <td> element and a text node, make the text
        var cell = document.createElement("td");
        var cellText = document.createTextNode("cell in row "+i+", column "+j);
  cell.appendChild(cellText);
  row.appendChild(cell);
}

  // add the row to the end of the table body
  tblBody.appendChild(row);
 }

// put the <tbody> in the <table>
tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
// appends <table> into <body>
 body.appendChild(tbl);
 // sets the border attribute of tbl to 2;
 tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");
}
```

Hope this helps. If this is not what you are looking for, please do comment your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to restyle your table by wrapping the `td`s in the `tr`s around in new lines, you can achieve that with CSS by displaying the `tr` as a grid.

CSS code:

```css
tr {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

Adjust the template columns and maybe also the template rows according to your needs.